# Negative TimeSpan To Negatime Double

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I am trying to subtract two time and if the result is Negative sign TimeSpan and i want it to split it with the result of still negative value of double the with the positive value of timespan to positive double.

```
    string date1 = "7:00 AM";
    string date2 = "7:15 AM";
    DateTime newdate1 = DateTime.Parse(date1);
    DateTime newdate2 = DateTime.Parse(date2);
    TimeSpan late = newdate1 - newdate2;
    string newlate = late.ToString();
    string[] split = newlate.Split(":");
    double num = double.Parse(split[0]) + (double.Parse(split[1]) / 60);
    if (num <= 0){
    Console.Write(num);
    }
    else{
        Console.Write("You didn't make it!!!");
    }
```

please help me with this area...

Comment: Could you provide some examples of inputs and expected outputs? Your description is not very clear to me.

Comment: Problem here is that `-00` is not negative as a double.

Comment: "i want it to split it with the result of still negative value of double the with the positive value of timespan to positive double" - I'm afraid I don't understand that at all. Please try to reword it, and as Good Night Nerd Pride says, provide examples of inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Why not just use `late.TotalHours`? Already of type double. And you can easily convert a negative `TimeSpan` to a positive with `-late`.

Comment: This seems overly complicated. If you want the the total minutes of a time span just do `var num = late.TotalMinutes;` – you don’t need to parse. (Also your parsing will fail on computers where the locale doesn’t use : as a time separator.) If you just want to check if the time span is negative do `if (late < TimeSpan.Zero)`.

Comment: You may also have alook at this [blog post](https://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) to see the problems `DateTime` have.

Comment: In fact you could just use `>` : https://dotnetfiddle.net/sHg8mj or https://dotnetfiddle.net/GKr40z